# Why is `sudo` different from `su -c` on Arch Linux when querying ip address?

Tags: sudo, archlinux, su

On my local Arch linux box, getting the local ip address, forces me to get a root shell or use `su -c`, whereas `sudo` times out. Anybody can explain why?

```
$ sudo ip address show
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

while `su -c` works:

```
$ su -c "ip address show"
Password:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Comment: Strange @Raf I'm working with 3 different Arch box and I just use `ip addr show` ...

Comment: yeah, ... me too. But on my current working machine, this is the experienced behavior. It obviously doesn't make any sense but not sure where to start looking. It's not showstopping so I tolerate this already for a couple of months. I'm just asking because of the unavoidable irritation when I'm `sudo`ing

Comment: do you have other command that have the same issue ? Cause if (I'm crazy) I `chmod 640` (default is 755)  `/usr/bin/ip` I have to execute it as `sudo` too !

Comment: so, one way or another `sudo ip address show` gets my wan ip whereas `su -c "ip address show"` lists the network interfaces (as I would expect). When I'm behind a firewall, this explains the timeout. Still don't know how it came about these 2 are different